# Reloading a div without reloading a page using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with amCharts and want to put a simple button in the my header that gives the option to refresh the chart chart div when needed.

I have looked all over the internet for a solution and all the code I have found is similar to what I am using, it does not want want to reload the div. Being new at JQUERY I am not sure what I doing wrong.

your assistance is greatly appreciated.

I have attached the JQUERY and HTML code Below:

```
<div id="chartwrapper">
    <!-- Unit Price Dollar -->
    <div id="unit-price" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;">VPM Global Select Opportunities Fund - Dollar Unit Price
        <br> Weekly: 2012/02/03 to 2014/10/24

    </div>
    <div id="chartdiv1" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>

    <!-- Unit Price Dollar Target Return -->
    <div id="unit-price-value" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;">Value of $1000 Invested at inception relative to Target Return
        <br> Weekly: 2012/02/03 to 2014/10/24
    </div>
    <div id="chartdiv2" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>

    <!-- Unit Price Rand Versus Inflation -->
    <div id="unit-price-rand" style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666; clear: both; margin-bottom: 20px;">Value of R1000 Invested at inception relative to Inflation Benchmarks
        <br> Weekly: 2012/02/03 to 2014/10/24
    </div>
    <div id="chartdiv3" style="width:100%; height:600px;"></div>

    <div style="text-align: center; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #666; clear: both;">
        <br>* VPM GSO - VPM Global Select Opportunities Fund
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
<!-- END CHART WRAPPER -->
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resetZoom1").bind("click", function() {
        var url = 'index.html';
        $("#chartwrapper").load( url + "div#chartdiv1")
    });
});
```

Comment: Try to add an extra space in the load url param, so it become:  `$("#chartwrapper").load( url + " div#chartdiv1")`. The url wil now look something like `...html div#chartdiv1` instead of `...htmldiv#chartdiv1`.

Comment: Also when you say "reload"... Don't you mean `div#chartwrapper` instead of `div#chartdiv1`?

Comment: chartwrapper is the container for all my chartdivs so I want to reload chartdiv1 within that container

Comment: Ok i see. Have you tried my first comment?

Comment: Hi Andreas I added that space and it just brings up a blank page now.  $("#chartwrapper").load( url + " div#chartdiv1"); did I understand you correctly.

Comment: Do you got any errors in the console?

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, **the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector** that determines the content to be loaded.

So, you must use a space:

```
$("#chartwrapper").load(url + " div#chartdiv1");
                  //           ^
                  // a space --'
```

Or, this is better (without `div`):

```
$("#chartwrapper").load(url + " #chartdiv1");
```

Comment: If you looked at the comments, you could see that this doesn't work for him